# How to fix different sizes?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

using this code on wpf i open 2 images of the same resolution, but on open is normal, second is much bigger, why?
I know that i can resize images before opening, and probably it will fix the problem, but i want to know why they different and how to fix it(Pixel height and PixelWidth that we recieve is also same)

```
    private void Image_Initialized(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var imagePath = OpenFileDialog();
        if (imagePath != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
            TestImage.Source = bitmap;
            TestImage.Height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
            TestImage.Width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            this.Height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
            this.Width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            TestImage.MouseDown += TestImage_MouseDown;
        }
    }
```

[smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzkOY.jpg)
[bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlUJL.jpg)

Comment: It is because the first jpg file's embedded dpi is 72. See [Images May Have Embedded DpiX and DpiY Information](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/04/15/277-images-may-have-embedded-dpix-and-dpiy-information/)

Comment: DPI should not be a problem when the PixelWidth/Height are used for an Image element's Width and Height as shown in the question. It is unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Don't you need a fixed size image control anyhow?